# What is the meaning of "primarian"?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm translating an interview of two musicians. At certain moment, discussing jokes hidden in lyrics, one of the speakers says "I think there's always been a couple of jokes in my work. It's not a primarian interest". And that's where my problem lies: I can't figure the meaning of "primarian". Dictionaries doesn't help much as neither of those I looked up seem to have this adjective. Google also doesn't suggest anything that would clarify the meaning for me. I'll be grateful for any help.

Comment: Can you provide the link to the extract?

Comment: It's a noun form of *primary* (and not a very common one). It's grammatically correct to use it to mean *primary* here, but strange, but then people mis-speak in strange ways. As is (that is to say, lacking any reason from a wider context to suspect otherwise) I'd consider it as being used to mean *primary*.

Comment: @Josh61, there are two:
[http://www.webheights.net/speakingcohen/images/underneath1094g.gif] and [http://www.webheights.net/speakingcohen/images/underneath1094h.gif] The paragraph starts at the end of the first page and ends on the second one.

Comment: @Jon Hanna, thank you very much for explanation. I thought so, but I wasn't sure I'm not taking the speaker wrong as it was the first time I encountered this word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It's not a primarian interest"

He means that when he writes the lyrics for a song, **his main objective** is not to insert  hidden jokes, although he admits he does that too.

Edit - "primarian" is not a word you can find in mainstream dictionaries, but it's been used colloquially (correctly or not) by some people to mean "primary" (of chief importance, principal) [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/primary)

Comment: thank you very much! I'm now sure I took the speaker right.

Comment: As Matt Gutting says: 'What we're really looking for (on this or any other Stack Exchange site) is a supported answer: one that you can support with authoritative references [in this case probably a dictionary, or some document]'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I've edited. As you already knew, there isn't such word. n.b. unlike many answerers I always give the reference when it is available.

Comment: I _wasn't_ aware that the word didn't exist: in fact, John Hanna (above) says it does. But like you, he offers no evidence 'authoritative reference') to support his claim. Thus _he_ considers it proper to only submit a 'comment'. Unsubstantiated arrogations, especially in 'answers', do not enhance the site's standing.

Comment: Based on my quick Google, "primarian" appears to be derived from "primal", not "primary".